# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number for /api.genius.com

Tags: php, curl

i am using Genius.com api for getting song information. For hiting the api i am using curl.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600); //timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
    // receive server response ...
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
        echo $error_msg;
        echo "\n";
        //throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Getting following error,

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

I have tried other ssl version also but that doesnot works
CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1, 
CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2, 
CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3, 
CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_3,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, all);
```

Works for me.